discrepancy between the frequency of joint_state_publish and robot_state_publish
I have a question.... for robot_state_publisher to reach 50 hz when publishing TF of continuous joints I need to set the joint_state_publish rate to 1000hz.
Is there a plausible explanation for why I need to set the rate of joint_state_publisher to 1000 Hz for the robot_state_publisher to achieve 50 Hz? Similar case to the one found in this thread:
similar post
I'm using ros noetic
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
     <param name="rate" type="int" value="1000"/>
    </node>


Can you clarify how you determined the " need".   There might be other things effecting your system. If you can share a reproduction we might be able to help you understand more.

By setting the ignore_timestamp parameter to "true" the difference between the frequency of joint_state_publish and robot_state_publish disappears.
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher">
<!--<param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0"/>-->
<param name="ignore_timestamp" type="bool" value="true"/>
</node>

The question remains, what would be the implications of setting the ignore_timestamp parameter to "true"?

The documentation says:  ignore_timestamp (bool)
If true, ignore the publish_frequency and the timestamp of joint_states and publish a tf for each of the received joint_states. Default is "false".
